# find() and fetchAll() are not working in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anybody suggest me what's wrong with my code? Although ***insert(), update() and delete()*** are working absolutely fine. This is my first project on the Zend framework and I'm messing with it form past two days and not getting what's actually going wrong with it. I'm using Zend Framework 1.

This is my function body.

```
public function getMenuCategoryById(Application_Model_MenuCategories $MenuCategory) {
        $where = array(
            'mc_id' => (int) $MenuCategory->__get('mc_id')
        );
        $result = $this->_db_table->find($where);
        echo '<pre';
        print_r($result);
        die();
        if (count($result) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $menuCategory = new Application_Model_MenuCategories($row);
        return $menuCategory;
    }
```

This is not returning the rows. Instead, it gives **Zend_Db_Table_Rowset bject** as below:

```
Zend_Db_Table_Rowset Object (
     [_data:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_table:protected] => Application_Model_DbTable_MenuCategories Object
         (
             [_name:protected] => menu_categories
             [_definition:protected] => 
             [_definitionConfigName:protected] => 
             [_db:protected] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object
                 (
                     [_pdoType:protected] => mysql
                     [_numericDataTypes:protected] => Array
                         (
                             [0] => 0
                             [1] => 1
                             [2] => 2
                             [INT] => 0
                             [INTEGER] => 0
                             [MEDIUMINT] => 0
                             [SMALLINT] => 0
                             [TINYINT] => 0
                             [BIGINT] => 1
                             [SERIAL] => 1
                             [DEC] => 2
                             [DECIMAL] => 2
                             [DOUBLE] => 2
                             [DOUBLE PRECISION] => 2
                             [FIXED] => 2
                             [FLOAT] => 2
                         )

                     [_defaultStmtClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                     [_config:protected] => Array
                         (
                             [dbname] => test_db
                             [host] => localhost
                             [username] => root
                             [password] => Password@123
                             [charset] => 
                             [persistent] => 
                             [options] => Array
                                 (
                                     [caseFolding] => 0
                                     [autoQuoteIdentifiers] => 1
                                     [fetchMode] => 2
                                 )

                             [driver_options] => Array
                                 (
                                 )

                         )

                     [_fetchMode:protected] => 2
                     [_profiler:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler Object
                         (
                             [_queryProfiles:protected] => Array
                                 (
                                 )

                             [_enabled:protected] => 
                             [_filterElapsedSecs:protected] => 
                             [_filterTypes:protected] => 
                         )

                     [_defaultProfilerClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler
                     [_connection:protected] => PDO Object
                         (
                         )

                     [_caseFolding:protected] => 0
                     [_autoQuoteIdentifiers:protected] => 1
                     [_allowSerialization:protected] => 1
                     [_autoReconnectOnUnserialize:protected] => 
                 )

             [_schema:protected] => 
             [_cols:protected] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => mc_id
                     [1] => category_name
                 )

             [_primary:protected] => Array
                 (
                     [1] => mc_id
                 )

             [_identity:protected] => 1
             [_sequence:protected] => 1
             [_metadata:protected] => Array
                 (
                     [mc_id] => Array
                         (
                             [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                             [TABLE_NAME] => menu_categories
                             [COLUMN_NAME] => mc_id
                             [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1
                             [DATA_TYPE] => int
                             [DEFAULT] => 
                             [NULLABLE] => 
                             [LENGTH] => 
                             [SCALE] => 
                             [PRECISION] => 
                             [UNSIGNED] => 
                             [PRIMARY] => 1
                             [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1
                             [IDENTITY] => 1
                         )

                     [category_name] => Array
                         (
                             [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                             [TABLE_NAME] => menu_categories
                             [COLUMN_NAME] => category_name
                             [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2
                             [DATA_TYPE] => varchar
                             [DEFAULT] => 
                             [NULLABLE] => 
                             [LENGTH] => 255
                             [SCALE] => 
                             [PRECISION] => 
                             [UNSIGNED] => 
                             [PRIMARY] => 
                             [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
                             [IDENTITY] => 
                         )

                 )

             [_metadataCache:protected] => 
             [_metadataCacheInClass:protected] => 1
             [_rowClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Table_Row
             [_rowsetClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Table_Rowset
             [_referenceMap:protected] => Array
                 (
                 )

             [_dependentTables:protected] => Array
                 (
                 )

             [_defaultSource:protected] => defaultNone
             [_defaultValues:protected] => Array
                 (
                 )

         )

     [_connected:protected] => 1
     [_tableClass:protected] => Application_Model_DbTable_MenuCategories
     [_rowClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Table_Row
     [_pointer:protected] => 0
     [_count:protected] => 0
     [_rows:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_stored:protected] => 1
     [_readOnly:protected] =>  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK - fetchAll() returns Zend_Db_Table_Rowset object. You can directly iterate it:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    // $row is Zend_Db_Table_Row object
}
```

or convert to array:

```
$arrayResult = $result->toArray();
```

However, dump of your `$result` shows that your query doesn't match any row in your table - check your `$where` conditions.

Comment: Okay. I tried this solution. But still, I have the problem.  **$arrayResult = $result->toArray();** give empty array. I also tried with **fetchAll()** but it gives empty array too.  Also **count($arrayResult)** gives 0.

Comment: I accidentally deleted all rows from DB. That's why I was getting these errors. My mistake. :D